# Symfony2 configuration setting for custom parameters in config.yml

Tags: symfony

I want to use `parameters.yml` for parameters, but top level name something like data in place of parameters. For this I did following things:

In `composer.json` in the root directory:

```
"extra": {
    "symfony-app-dir": "app",
    "symfony-web-dir": "web",
    "incenteev-parameters": 
    {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml",
        "parameter-key": "data"
    }  
}
```

In `parameters.yml` and `parmeters.yml.dist` like this:

```
data:
    database_driver: pdo_mysql
```

But still when I am running command php composer.phar update, I get an error:

```
  [Symfony\Component\Config\Exception\FileLoaderLoadException]
  Cannot import resource "D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony_two\app/config\parameters.y
  ml" from "D:\xampp\htdocs\symfony_two\app/config\config.yml". (There is no
  extension able to load the configuration for "data" (in D:\xampp\htdocs\s
  ymfony_two\app/config\parameters.yml). Looked for namespace "config", found
  "framework", "security", "twig", "monolog", "swiftmailer", "assetic", "doc
  trine", "sensio_framework_extra", "forma_test", "custom_customer", "acme_de
  mo", "web_profiler", "sensio_distribution")
```

I am not getting. Am I missing something for defining data somewhere?

Comment: Can you show the piece of the `config.yml` fil where you use the `data`?

Comment: doctrine:
  dbal:
        default_connection: default
        connections:
            default:
                driver:   "%data.database_driver%"
                host:     "%data.database_host%"
                port:     "%data.database_port%"
                dbname:   "%data.database_name%"
                user:     "%data.database_user%"
                password: "%data.database_password%"

Comment: In parameters.yml and parameters.yml.dst# This file is auto-generated during the composer install
data:
   database_driver: pdo_mysql
   database_host: 127.0.0.1
   database_port: null
   database_name: forma_test
   database_user: root
   database_password: root

Comment: Thanks for doing good formatting.